# How best to change SQL passwords and update all the connection strings on a farm?

Tags: powershell

I am very new to Powershell and was wondering if it is possible to accomplish the following, which is based on a requirement to change SQL passwords every 3 months and update all the websites whose web.config files have connections strings at the same time to the new SQL password.
Ideally the new SQL passwords, server names & databases could be stored in a file (SQL table, XML files, csv, etc) and the script reads in the file.  Then the script changes the SQL Passwords based on the content of a table that contains the names of the servers and databases.  Immediately after step 1, the script updates the web.configs connection strings in about 20 websites to the new password used in step 1.  I guess I need a table to hold the path to the web.configs too.  Then it repeats the process by changing a SQL password and updating another 20 websites.
Nice to have would be creating a backup copy of the web.config prior to modifying it and wrapping the script in transaction just in case the script encounters an error.
Thanks

Comment: You explained what you want to do.  Have you Googled how to do each step and tried it?  You should give this a shot, document specific issues, troubleshoot them further on Google, and then when you are stuck, revise this question with the specific issues you came across.

Comment: I Googled how to change a password in the web.config using powershell and was encouraged.  Then I thought I am not the only person who has had to deal with this problem and was hoping someone who had done this would offer some top of mind advice.

Comment: @timchisholm understandable, but that's not how this site works. Please read [ask] to get an idea of what is and is not on topic here. This question is too broad.

Comment: You might be in the minority of people that have done this because often you use _windows authentication_ in your connection strings, which means that you have a lot less places to change passwords. In fact using windows authentication means there are no passwords in connection strings ever. I'm suprised you have 3 month password change rule but it hasn't been identified that you should avoid passwords in connection strings.